# Heroku Free and Paid Dynos permissions

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to use this package on my node app.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping
(i.e. The app I'm working on pings other sites using this package)

It appears that it is not permitted on free dynos.

I was wondering if there will be permissions if I get the paid dynos.

Comment: You should ask Dynos support about this.

Comment: They don't have pre sales support. I will try to ask over at salesforce. Ill post the update here if I get results over there.